# Identify when curl command has finished successfully

Tags: bash, curl

I have a script which using a curl command to send a request to a web service, the output of the web service is written to a file.
The file is then moved to another location.

Instead of using a delay in the script (to wait for the completion of writing the output to a file) is there any way to identify whether the curl command has finished successfully and the output has been written to a file?

I want to avoid a scenario when I'm moving the file while information is still being written to it.

Appreciate your input

Comment: Why would you even think of using a delay?  Are you running curl in the background? If not, just put the `mv` command on the next line, or after a `;` (or, better yet, `&&`).

Answer (score 5):

Why would you be using a delay, and why would you need to move the file?

Just write the file in the correct place to start with:

```
curl -o /path/to/correct/place/filename URL
```

Curl exits with a zero exit status if it terminates without error. You may use this fact to move the file into the correct location only when Curl is successful:

```
curl -o file URL && mv file /some/place
```

Or, if you need to do some error reporting:

```
if curl -o file URL; then
    mv file /some/place
    # or, to use sftp:
    #      printf 'put file\n' | sftp -b - user@host 
else
    printf 'Curl failed with error code "%d" (check the manual)\n' "$?" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I see that using a delay is not the way to go. I need to move/copy the file to a sftp (public key authentication is in place). Any idea what approach would be best to use?

Comment: @Borka See the comments in the last bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&` for `curl` and `mv` command. in this case `mv` will execute only if previous `curl` command was executed successfully.

```
curl .... >to_file && mv to_file /to/dest
```

If you need to move file across sftp server, use below command.

```
sftp USER@HOST:/path/in/remote/dest <<< $'put /path/to/local/to_file'
```

Or even **directly write in remote sftp path the FILE `curl` will output**.

```
sftp USER@HOST:/path/in/remote/dest <<< $'put /path/to/local/"$(curl -o FILE URL)"'
```